# Ссылки в canvas

Tags: html5

Такой вопрос - есть canvas, в нем нарисованы несколько кругов, которые реагируют на движение мышки. Можно ли как-то к этим кругам привязать ссылки на определенные страницы. То есть при клике на определенный arc, посетителя перекидывает на определенную страницу.

Comment: Боюсь что никак, разве что при наведении на нужную область пересисовывать саму "ссылку", а при клике делать location.href или window.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет!

Используйте карты изображений

```
<map name="karta"><area shape="poly" coords="0,1,2,3" /></map>
```

Подробнее смотрите доки по HTML, полностью синтаксис не припомню.